# While creating this java program in oracle db. Im facing some errors. CAn anyone tell me the way to compile it. the code is as follows

Tags: java, oracle, plsqldeveloper

Below code is working properly in eclipse. But I,m trying to create this source in oracle 11g Db. While creating it throws some warnings.

```
create or replace
and compile java source named "Noitime"
as
package com;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;

public class Noitime {
public String attr(String filepath,String filename)
{
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
FileTime fileTime = FileTime.fromMillis(time);
Path path = Paths.get(filepath,filename);

try {
Files.setLastModifiedTime(path, fileTime);
return "Success";
} catch (IOException e) {
System.err.println(e);

return "Fail";
}
}
}
```

Comment: What's with the complete lack of indentation?

Comment: what warnings are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have garbled the error/warning message, but I think that it is telling you that you should be using the pathname "com/Noitime.java" when compiling.  The pathname you use should correspond to the full class name, and the full class name is "com.Noitime".